# Error: Cannot Resolve notifyDataSetChanged(); Android

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm having some trouble with updating my ListView.

So I used notifyDataSetChanged(); but it says that it can't be resolved.

Heres the part of the code that is not working:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    background2= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    final ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Intent calledActivity=getIntent();
    final List pe=calledActivity.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Caller1");

    String []s =new String[pe.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<pe.size();i++)
    {
        s[i]=(String)pe.get(i);
    }

            final ListAdapter theAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pe);
             theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    final int cnt=1;
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String s1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            pe.remove(s1);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    theAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });



        }
    });


    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `theAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in a `Runnable`?

Comment: I read it as a solution to another persons issue

Comment: Have you tried removing `theAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from the `Runnable` and putting it directly after `pe.remove(s1);`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged` is not a method of `ListAdapter`, but of `BaseAdapter`, (ArrayAdapter is a subclass of BaseAdapter). To fix you can simply cast the ListAdapter

```
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String s1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            pe.remove(s1);
             ((BaseAdapter)theAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` works with `ArrayAdapter` as well. I have used it and it works just fine.

Comment: Gradle will take some time but I think it should work. Fingers crossed.

Comment: it does, but if you take a closer look to the op's code, you will notice that he is assigning the ArrayApdater instance to a ListAdapter @iRuth

Comment: @Blackbelt  Yes i have used ArrayAdapter, following Derek Banas's YouTube tutorial no.3

Comment: try with `((ArrayAdapter)theAdapter).remove((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));`

Comment: Should I use it in place of notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: okay since the emulator is still loading its gonna take some time, i'll get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Turns out that your first suggestion works. Thank you so much, you don't know how much this means to me.  :)